# Exception always being thrown

Tags: java, exception

What I want to happen is for a file to be read from and the text is stored in in a String array called data[]. data[3] should contain either "Warning Lights are red", or "Warning Lights are green" and in the case it is corrupted and contains neither I defined a custom exception that I would like to be thrown. My code is as follows:

```
if(data[3].equals("Warning Lights are red")){
             //do something
         }
         else if(data[3].equals("Warning Lights are green")){
             //do something
         }
         else if(!data[3].equals("Warning Lights are red") && !data[3].equals("Warning Lights are green")){
             throw  new FileCorruptionException("Unfortunately the status file was corrupted, please try printing to the file again to fix this issue.");

         }
```

and the issue I am having is that the FileCorruptionException is always being thrown even if data[3] is indeed equal to either "Warning Lights are red" or "Warning Lights are green", I have checked in the text file to confirm this. I suspect I have a logical error but I dont know what it could be. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `data[3]` doesn't contain what you think it does. Have you output its value and its length to check?

Comment: Check for spurious whitespace.

Comment: Clearly at least one of the things you've asserted in your question cannot be true, otherwise your code would run as expected.  You should reduce this to a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to explore the issue more thoroughly.

Comment: also, i would try making the string lowercase and comparing in case data[3] is "Warning lights are red" and not "Warning Lights are red"

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I confirmed with a print statement that `data[3]` does contain the text read from the file which is as I expected. and it does match the case exactly as I have written with being either "Warning Lights are red" or "Warning Lights are green"

Comment: @ez4nick: Again, that cannot be the case, otherwise your code would work.  So again, please construct a test-case that demonstrates this...

Comment: Simple test: http://pastebin.com/aBfsg1Hu It works. The problem is another (post where you read the file) (and anyway the else if is useless, just else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have some whitespace, like a new line at the end of the string. Try this to check if there's any whitespace:

```
System.out.print(":" + data[3] + ":")
```

You could use [`String.trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to remove leading and trailing whitespace:

```
if (data[3].trim().equals() ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a lexical problem. There is probably a difference in the whitespace in your conditional and the whitespace in `data[3]`. Check for additional whitespace after red/green in the `data[3]` string. Hope this helps.

Edit: also you could just use an `else` instead of an `else if` to throw the exception, if you don't have other cases to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `String.equals()`. May be there is some case issue.

There is no need to put a check in last `else if` because you have already checked it in first two conditions.

```
     if(data[3].equalsIgnoreCase("Warning Lights are red")){
         //do something
     }
     else if(data[3].equalsIgnoreCase("Warning Lights are green")){
         //do something
     }
     else{
         throw  new FileCorruptionException("Unfortunately the status file was corrupted, please try printing to the file again to fix this issue.");
     }
```